# How can I pass content of Chrome internal page to a shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I would like to be able to pass the content of this internal chrome page to a file "about:gpu" but I don't know how.

All this with bash commands. I would appreciate your help

Comment: wget -o about:gp url

Answer (score 0):

this bash oneliner works for me (with chromium - but I am almost sure that it works also with chrome)

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser   --headless  --dump-dom  chrome://gpu/   > gpu.html
```

BTW: in case you wonder: I have also checked that it works also in windows

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"   --headless  --dump-dom  chrome://gpu/   > gpu.html
```